# Ubuntu server, monit email, postfix piping

Tags: postfix-mta, monit

I have a specific setup to pipe incoming emails on an ubuntu server. When emails are sent to name@myserver.com they are filtered and piped to a php script
The postfix specific configuration for this piping is as follow (in brief):

```
**main.cf:**

...
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
...


**master.cf**

mydestination =  myserver.com, localhost.myserver, localhost
...
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=myhook:dummy

...
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       -       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
...

myhook      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=www-data  null_sender=  argv=//admin/get_mail.php   ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}

**access file:**

name@myserver.com FILTER myhook:dummy
```

Now everything is working fine when emails are sent to 'myserver.com'. Messages are filtered and the php script is triggered.

The problem comes with monit service that is running on the server.
Emails sent by monit from myserver.com are filtered by myhook when emails are sent by the service and sent to the piped php script while they should not and directly sent out to the receipient...

It looks like postfix filter settings are not working in that case.
Curiously, email sent be other web application from the server and going out as they should (from www-data@myserver.com).

Specific configuration for minitrc are:

```
set mailserver localhost
set mail-format { from: monit@myserver.com }
set alert monit@anotherdomain.com
```

Could you help my figure out what could be the conflict between monit and postfix here?

thank you.